# How can we change build properties of Android Emulators?

Tags: android, linux, android-studio, android-emulator

We are running multiple Android Emulators in parallel.
How can we change emulator properties (like Manufacturer, Device name, Product Model, Build Serial Number, IMEI etc) so that different emulators will run with different properties at the same time.

I to change some properties such as Manufacture,Device name,Product Model, Build Serial Number, IMEI number
so that the emulator properties looks like a physical device's properties

There is a provision to change these properties in official Android Developer website.You take help from this link
https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#advanced (search for -prop) But not working.

I am already able change timezone of emulators.

### Setting-up emulators (Ubuntu 18.04)

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
wget https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip
unzip sdk-tools-linux-4333796.zip -d android-sdk
```

define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/$USER/android-sdk in /etc/environment.
add ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools and ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools to system path.

Re-login is required after setting the path
Make sure all the above paths are present.
To check path by command

```
sudo env
```

```
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --update
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86"
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "emulator"
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "platform-tools"
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager "build-tools;28.0.3"
cd /home/$USER/android-sdk/
mkdir "platforms"
```

#### Creating Emulators

Creating AVD_0001 . we can create multiple emulators by changing names like AVD_0002,AVD_0003 ...

```
/home/$USER/android-sdk/tools/bin/avdmanager --verbose create avd --force --name "AVD_0001" --device "pixel" --package "system-images;android-28;google_apis;x86" --tag "google_apis" --abi "x86" -p "/home/$USER/android-sdk/avd/AVD_0001"
```

#### Start Multiple Emulators

Each emulators need two different ports. Example: AVD_0001 (5554,5555), AVD_0002 (5556,5557)...

```
sudo /home/$USER/android-sdk/emulator/emulator @AVD_0001 -ports 5554,5555 -timezone America/New_York -no-boot-anim -netdelay none -no-snapshot -no-audio -gpu swiftshader_indirect
```

Comment: Did you get a working solution to the question ?

Comment: I have come across a scenario where I want the emulator to return random values for API calls like getDeviceID and getImei. By default emulators respond with "00000000000..." for getImei API call. How do I change this ?